# Distribution vs Development Release [Linux]

Tags: linux-distributions

I was browsing DistroWatch.com and I was wondering what is the difference between a Distribution and a Development Release in linux. Can anyone enlighten me....

Comment: The Distribution release is a stable release and the development is under work?? I wanted to know what to download...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A distribution release is when a release is 'stable', or ready for general public.

A development release is an alpha, beta, or release candidate that is still undergoing testing, and may work, but is not ready for general public.